# Couchdb get brands' all category

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

The document has two field: brand and category.

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.db_type == 'product') {
        emit([doc.brand, doc.category], null);
    }
}
```

in group_level1, the result would be all brands.
in group_level2, the result would be all unique brand and category.

What if I want to get the all brands and associate categories.

something like the key are the brand name and the value are its categories.

So, I can iterate the result.

Here is some sample data:

- brand: A, category: fruit
- brand: A, category: fruit
- brand: A, category: car
- brand: B, category: fruit

What I want is:

- key: brandA, value: [fruit, car]
- key: brandB, value:[fruit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.db_type == 'product') {
    emit(doc.brand, doc.category);
  }
}

function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    var category = {};
    for (var index in values) {
        category[values[index]] = values[index];
    }
    return category;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query your existing view with `reduce=false`. The keys are returned in the resultset (in order) so you can iterate over them.

If you wanted to get only the categories associated with a specific brand, you could specify `startkey=[<brand>]&endkey=[<brand>,{}]` as well.

Comment: redece=false, I will got multiple copy of categories, I want to put all categories into a set, every category is unique.

Comment: with startkey and endkey, I am not query anthing. I want to get all.

Comment: I have to use group level1 to get all brands, iterate brands, use startkey and endkey to get all categories, the total request count would be 1 + count(brands), Can I do it just in one request?

Comment: I think Will is correct. @luthur, could you possibly add some example data and what you would like to see as a result? I think maybe we are still misunderstanding something. Thanks!